# invalid command name "!canvas" how do i fix it?

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas

So i have made a fully working catch the egg game but when i lose all of my lives it brings up this very strange error that i have never seen before that says:(see below) and i don't have any clue of what to do but i will show you of what the script is(see under the error). I have searched on google for hours upon hours trying to find out why it says this random mistake that doesn't even affect the gameplay.

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\SDC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\SDC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 814, in callit
    func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\SDC\Documents\python projects\catch the egg.py", line 50, in move_eggs
    (egg_x, egg_y, egg_x2, egg_y2) = c.coords(egg)
  File "C:\Users\SDC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2766, in coords
    self.tk.call((self._w, 'coords') + args))]
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!canvas"

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

from itertools import cycle
from random import randrange
from tkinter import Canvas, Tk, messagebox, font

canvas_width = 800
canvas_height = 400

root = Tk()
c = Canvas(root, width = canvas_width, height = canvas_height, background="deep sky blue")
c.create_rectangle(-5, canvas_height - 100, canvas_width + 5, canvas_height + 5, fill = "sea green",  width=0)
c.create_oval(-80, -80, 120, 120, fill="orange", width=0)
c.pack()

color_cycle = cycle(["light blue", "light green", "light pink", "light yellow", "light cyan"])
egg_width = 45
egg_height = 55
egg_score = 10
egg_speed = 500
egg_interval = 4000
difficulty_factor = 0.95

catcher_color = "blue"
catcher_width = 100
catcher_height = 100
catcher_start_x = canvas_width / 2 - catcher_width / 2
catcher_start_y = canvas_height - catcher_width - 20
catcher_start_x2 = catcher_start_x + catcher_width
catcher_start_y2 = catcher_start_y + catcher_height
catcher = c.create_arc(catcher_start_x, catcher_start_y, catcher_start_x2, catcher_start_y2, start = 200, extent = 140, \
                       style = "arc", outline = catcher_color, width = 3)

game_font = font.nametofont("TkFixedFont")
game_font.config(size = 18)
score = 0
score_text = c.create_text(10, 10, anchor="nw" , font=game_font, fill="darkblue", text="Score: " + str(score))

lives_remaining = 3
lives_text = c.create_text(canvas_width - 10, 10, anchor="ne", font = game_font, fill="darkblue", text = "Lives " + str(lives_remaining))

eggs = []
def create_egg():
    x = randrange(10, 740)
    y = 40
    new_egg = c.create_oval(x, y, x + egg_width, y + egg_height, fill = next(color_cycle), width=0)
    eggs.append(new_egg)
    root.after(egg_interval, create_egg)

def move_eggs():
    for egg in eggs:
        (egg_x, egg_y, egg_x2, egg_y2) = c.coords(egg)
        c.move(egg, 0, 10)
        if egg_y2 > canvas_height:
            egg_dropped(egg)
    root.after(egg_speed, move_eggs)

def egg_dropped(egg):
    eggs.remove(egg)
    lose_a_life()
    if lives_remaining == 0:
        messagebox.showinfo("Game Over!", "Final Score: " + str(score))
        root.destroy()

def lose_a_life():
    global lives_remaining
    lives_remaining -= 1
    c.itemconfigure(lives_text, text = "Lives: " + str(lives_remaining))

def check_catch():
    catcher_x, catcher_y, catcher_x2, catcher_y2 = c.coords(catcher)
    for egg in eggs:
        egg_x, egg_y, egg_x2, egg_y2 = c.coords(egg)
        if catcher_x - 10 < egg_x and egg_x2 < catcher_x2 + 10 and (catcher_y2 - egg_y2) < 5:
            eggs.remove(egg)
            c.delete(egg)
            increase_score(egg_score)
    root.after(100, check_catch)
    
def increase_score(points):
    global score, egg_speed, egg_interval
    score += points
    egg_speed = int(egg_speed * difficulty_factor)
    egg_interval = int(egg_interval * difficulty_factor)
    c.itemconfigure(score_text, text="Score: " + str(score))

def move_left(event):
    (x1, y1, x2, y2) = c.coords(catcher)
    if x1 > 0:
        c.move(catcher, -20, 0)

def move_right(event):
    (x1, y1, x2, y2) = c.coords(catcher)
    if x2 < canvas_width:
        c.move(catcher, 20, 0)

c.bind("<Left>" , move_left)
c.bind("<Right>" , move_right)
c.focus_set()

root.after(1000, create_egg)
root.after(1000, move_eggs)
root.after(1000, check_catch)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I told you, it's canvas trying to find an egg which isn't there anymorem

Comment: oh so i still don't get what i am supposed to do to removed this oor is there any way to do so?

Comment: I don't think, so. You can catch the error with try except.

Comment: oh ok so it is basically impossible to solve

Comment: That error is usually the result of the canvas being deleted, and then you trying to call a method on it after it has been deleted.

Comment: Do you have any idea of which 2 lines are doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `move_egg` is still in the loop when you destroy the window. One way to overcome it is to check if `lives_remaining` is `0` and break the loop if it is equal.

```py
def move_eggs():
    for egg in eggs:
        (egg_x, egg_y, egg_x2, egg_y2) = c.coords(egg)
        c.move(egg, 0, 10)
        if egg_y2 > canvas_height:
            egg_dropped(egg)
            if lives_remaining == 0:
                return

    root.after(egg_speed, move_eggs)
```

Comment: i did exactly the improvements that you have put but it became the same output should i edit the post to the one that you said and see what i did wrong?

Comment: @Hallows my bad I have now updated the answer.

Comment: oh thank you so much it worked now the script works perfectly fine and i will accept the answer